# Changes in the JS file are not reflected in the Spring Framework

Tags: javascript, spring, clear-cache

I created a build file for use with the Spring Framework with webpack. The generated file is "... /webapp/resources/js/build.js". The problem is that the changes in the JS file have not been reflected in the browser despite the changes.

For example, changes are not reflected when I press F5 in browser. How can I reflect changed js file? I want to ensure that the js file is not cached in the browser to reflect that js has changed. How do I clear the cache?

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem and I found ignoring the cache or clearing browser cache to do the trick.

Ignoring the cache: hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh page ignoring the cache.

Clearing the cache: hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> will bring you to a screen where you can select the option to clear cached images and files.

You should now see the changes you made to your JavaScript file.